# Error when trying to convert a list of objects in a string using reduce function

Tags: kotlin, reduce

I am playing with kotlin language and I tried the following code:

```
data class D( val n: Int, val s: String )
val lst = listOf( D(1,"one"), D(2, "two" ) )
val res  = lst.reduce { acc:String, d:D  ->  acc + ", " + d.toString()  }
```

The last statement causes the following errors:

```
    Expected parameter of type String
    Expected parameter of type String
    Type mismatch: inferred type is D but String was expected
```

while this version of the last statement works:

```
val res = lst.map { e -> e.toString() }.reduce {  acc, el -> acc + ", " +  el }
```

I do not understand why the first version does not work. The formal definition of the reduce function, found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html), is the following:

```
inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(
    operation: (acc: S, T) -> S
): S
```

But this seems in contrast with the following sentence, on the same page:

> Accumulates value starting with the first element and applying
> operation from left to right to current accumulator value and each
> element.

That is, as explained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-aggregate.html#fold-and-reduce):

> The difference between the two functions is that fold() takes an
> initial value and uses it as the accumulated value on the first step,
> whereas the first step of reduce() uses the first and the second
> elements as operation arguments on the first step.

But, to be able to apply the *operation* on first and second element, and so on, it seems to me tha the operation shall have both arguments of the base type of the Iterable.

So, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Reduce is not the right tool here. The best function in this case is [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html):

```
listOf(D(1, "one"), D(2, "two"))
    .joinToString(", ")
    .let { println(it) }
```

This prints:

```
D(n=1, s=one), D(n=2, s=two)
```

---

`reduce` is not designed for converting types, it's designed for reducing a collection of elements to a single element **of the same type**. You don't want to reduce to a single `D`, you want a string. You could try implementing it with [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html), which is like `reduce` but takes an initial element you want to fold into:

```
listOf(D(1, "one"), D(2, "two"))
    .fold("") { acc, d -> "$acc, $d" }
    .let { println(it) }
```

However, this will add an extra comma:

```
, D(n=1, s=one), D(n=2, s=two)
```

Which is exactly why `joinToString` exists.

Comment: Ok thanks. Good to know about joinToString.  But  according to the definition, the type of the result (S)  could be different from  the iterable base type  (T). Is the definition incorrect. or it is me that does not understand it ?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got `S` from. The result is always `String`. `toString()` is called on the iterated elements to convert them to strings by default, but you can also provide your own transform function.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the definition to understand why its not working

To make it work, you can simply create an extension function:

```
fun List<D>.reduce(operation: (acc: String, D) -> String): String {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Empty list can't be reduced.")
    var accumulator = this[0].toString()
    for (index in 1..lastIndex) {
        accumulator = operation(accumulator, this[index])
    }
    return accumulator
}
```

you can use it as:

```
val res  = lst.reduce { acc:String, d:D  ->  acc + ", " + d.toString()  }
```

or simply:

```
val res  = lst.reduce { acc, d -> "$acc, $d" }
```

You can modify the function to be more generic if you want to.

Comment: No need to write a new function, use [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html).

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Your code `acc:String` is already a false statement inside this line:

```
val res  = lst.reduce { acc:String, d:D  ->  acc + ", " + d.toString()  }
```

Because `acc` can only be `D`, never a `String`! `Reduce` returns the same type as the Iterable it is performed on and `lst` is `Iterable<D>`.

### Explanation

You already looked up the definition of reduce

```
inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(
    operation: (acc: S, T) -> S
): S
```

so lets try to put your code inside:

1. `lst` is of type `List<D>`
2. since `List` extends `Iterable`, we can write `lst : Iterable<D>`
3. `reduce` will look like this now:

```kotlin
inline fun <D, T : D> Iterable<T>.reduce(
     operation: (acc: D, T) -> D //String is literally impossible here, because D is not a String
): S
```

and written out:

```kotlin
lst<D>.reduce { acc:D, d:D  ->  }
```